# Automapper Throwing Odd Mapping Error

Tags: automapper, .net-4.5

Automapper is throwing this error at me: `Missing map from String to String. Create using Mapper.CreateMap<String, String>.`

The map is used in two places. in one place it works fine, in another it fails.

The mapping profile is this:

```
public class AdminUserProfileProfile: Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<AdminUser, AdminUserProfile>()
              .ForMember(vm => vm.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
              .ForMember(vm => vm.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Name))
              .ForMember(vm => vm.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Email))
              .ForMember(vm => vm.Roles, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Roles.Select(r => r.Name)))
              .IgnoreAllNonExisting();
    }
}
```

The only difference in use case is that the mapping which behaves as expected uses `Mapper.Map<AdminUserProfile>(entity)` and the one that fails is used via a `Project().To' call.

I would like to use the projection capabilities of `Project().To<>`, what do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: Sadly no, I never managed to work this one out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just spent some time in the `AutoMapper` source figuring this out. The issue comes from a bug in type handling, but there's not an easy fix in the automapper source.

TL;DR: If you make `AdminUserProfile.Roles` be of type `IEnumerable<string>`, I think it will work.

```cs
.ForMember(vm => vm.Roles, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Roles.Select(r => r.Name)))
```

I'll bet a dollar `AdminUserProfile.Roles` is something like `string[]`, `ICollection<string>`, or `List<string>`.

AutoMapper is trying to assemble a linq query that looks kinda like this:

```cs
admins.Select(a => new AdminUserProfile{
  Id = a.Id,
  Name = a.Name,
  Roles = a.Roles.Select(r => r.Name)
})
```

But that isn't legal, because the types on `Roles = a.Roles.Select(r => r.Name)` don't match. In my case, my `Roles` property was a `ICollection<string>`, but `a.Roles.Select` is returning an `IEnumerable<string>`, and you can't assign those directly.

I patched the automapper source to fix the `Missing map from String to String.` error, and once past that it will try to add a `ToList` in there, generating something like:

```cs
admins.Select(a => new AdminUserProfile{
  Id = a.Id,
  Name = a.Name,
  Roles = a.Roles.Select(r => r.Name).ToList()
})
```

This is neat, but if you use it with Linq-to-entities you'll get a runtime `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ToList` error.

I think the "real" fix would be to make significant changes to automapper and have it generate something like:

```cs
admins.Select(a => new {
  a.Id,
  a.Name,
  Roles = a.Roles.Select(r => r.Name)
})
.AsEnumerable() // run the linq-to-entities query
.Select(a => new AdminUserProfile{
  Id = a.Id,
  Name = a.Name,
  Roles = a.Roles.ToList()
})
```

The code is pretty dense, so I'm unlikely to make this fix.

I'd recommend just change `AdminUserProfile.Roles` to `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Awesome answer, I've assigned some bounty to say thanks.